# Python ElasticSearch DSL Truncating Results

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to utilize the elasticsearch dsl library in python but I seem to be getting some kind of truncated results/metadata instead of a document/response object. Sanitized query below:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q, F
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import MultiMatch
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import requests
import json  

client = Elasticsearch("")

s = Search().using(client).query("match", id="1") 
response = s.execute()
test_response = response.json()
```

Which gives this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'json'
```

I was hoping to use the newer DSL to keep things less verbose.  Has anyone encountered something like this or have any tips.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The result of `execute()` is the parsed JSON already (the structure is the same as with response from the HTTP API):

```
print(response.hits.total)
```

You can also iterate over the results as follows ([documentation](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/search_dsl.html#hits)):

```
for h in response:
   print(h.title, h.body)
```

Comment: Interesting.  Do you have any hunch as to why I am seeing the following then "u'request_attributes': {},...}" ?  My results appear to be getting truncated for some reason.  I have validate they are by logging into plugin/head .

Comment: Are you sure to follow the advice on picking the correct version of the libraries to your Elasticsearch version (http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#compatibility)?

Comment: Hmmm, that could be the issue.  I see the details in the startup guide.   When I initially installed the elasticsearch-dsl via pip it downgraded elasticsearch from 2.2.0 to 1.9.0 and I did not notice.  Since I am just using jupyter notebooks at the moment, I'll have to find a workaround for the setup.py/requirements.txt need.

Comment: I did the following: pip install git+git://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py.git Which seems to solve my versioning conflict "Successfully installed elasticsearch-2.2.0 elasticsearch-dsl-2.0.0.dev0"  Still seem to be having the issue though, unfortunately.

Comment: @Pylander what do you have `Elasticsearch("<here>")`? Are you connecting to Elasticsearch directly or through some proxy?

Comment: It is connect directly to the host.  I have held off on following up on this and found come other issues with elastic search I am solving first.  Will update this question eventually.